# How to find Duplicates in an 3 Dimensional list

Tags: python, list

Hello i want to build a Highscore List with the Attributes [Position,Name,Points].
If they have the same Points, they should share the Position.
ex. [[1,John,55],[2,Anna,35],[2,Mike,35],[3,Tom,15]].

First I tried to sort the List after the Points, my next Step is to rewrite the Position

`

```
l = [[4,Anna,35], [2,John,55], [1,Tom,15], [3,Mike,35], [5,Sepp,35]]
count = 0
for i in l:  # sort the List after Points
    l[count][2] = int(l[count][2])
    count = count + 1
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
position = 1
for i, j in enumerate(l[:-1][2]): # rewrite the Position 
    if j == l[i + 1][2]:
        l[i][0] = position
        l[i + 1][0] = position

    else:
        l[i][0] = position
        position = position + 1
```

`

How can rewrite the Position correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort by the last element of each list (score) and then update the first element of each list (position) to match the index in the outer list?

All that's needed:

```
l = [
    [4, 'Anna', 35], 
    [2, 'John', 55], 
    [1, 'Tom', 15], 
    [3, 'Mike', 35], 
    [5, 'Sepp', 35]
]
l = sorted(l, key=lambda rec: rec[-1])
l = [[i, *rec[1:]] for i, rec in enumerate(l)]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'Tom', 15], [1, 'Anna', 35], [2, 'Mike', 35], [3, 'Sepp', 35], [4, 'John', 55]]
```

Or, starting at 1 of course:

```
l = [[i+1, *rec[1:]] for i, rec in enumerate(l)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'Tom', 15], [2, 'Anna', 35], [3, 'Mike', 35], [4, 'Sepp', 35], [5, 'John', 55]]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. The Problem is, that Anna, Mike and Sepp share the same points (35). So they should also share the same Position (2)